# Bigot and Hypocrite - What's the difference?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

What's the difference between the two.

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Comment: They can be the same thing - http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=8cc_1352405973

Comment: These words aren't synonyms as @Ronan points out. Bigot: pre-judges people based on color, etc. Hypocrites (hypo = low, crit - truth) supports certain rules, but then breaks those rules himself. Example: a strong gun control advocate owning a large collection of guns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "bigot" is someone who is ignorant of others because of prejudiced views.

A "hyprocrite" is someone who complains about something and then does the same thing themselves.